# Nodejs: Challenge to read add(2)(3) and add(2,3) from STDIN and return the sum on STDOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js

Well my friend just asked me to solve this:
Type following in STDIN:

add(2)(3)
add(2,3)

and get the following output on STDOUT:

5
5

Well I dont know how this can be done on a nodejs platform. I have the following code in javascript but it ain't giving me any output. I am not sure this code is correct either.

```
var add = function (a) {
return function (b) {return a + b;};
};
```

NOTE: I have to invoke this function from STDIN.
Since I am new to nodejs i just cant figure out how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for in its most basic form is probably this one. This can be easily extended to accept any amount of numbers.

```
var add = function add() {
    var cache;
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        cache = arguments[0];
        return function ( number ) {return cache + number;};
    }
    else return arguments[0] + arguments[1];
};
```

You'll have to figure out on yourself how the whole process.stdin works, since I haven't worked with that yet.